# Automatically fill in parent object on a case

Tags: case

I have two objects:

`parent_object__c` and `related_object__c`

I have a lookup to both objects on my case, but I only allow the creation of the case from the related object. However, I want to automatically fill in the parent object field. Can I do this without code? I thought I could use a lookup filter, but it doesn't seem to work, or am I doing something wrong? Tia.

Comment: simple trigger would solve this issue, but you woul have to code a bit

Comment: create a workflow rule with a field update for parent object field on case in which you can use a formula to get the parent object id from the related object record.